# 5 finger Schunk SVH Hand

Tags: ros, schunk

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am working on object Grasping using Schunk SVH hand.

I have the following questions -

1. Is there any other institution / organization working on a similar project ?
2. Is there any grasp planning library in ROS ( or C++) available for Schunk SVH Hand ? If not for Schunk hand, then for any other 4/5 fingers hand ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203073/5-finger-schunk-svh-hand/) by [Harsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21631/harsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-02-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-02-13**:
You might want to checkout the [ipa320](https://github.com/ipa320) repository, they have some Schunk related packages. Also: the ROS Index site returns quite some results for *schunk*, see [here](http://rosindex.github.io/search/?q=schunk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Heyho,

at least for simple grasps you can just rely on the internal position/current controller by closing it completely. This produced good results, also for fragile objects. But of course that is not really what you want.

You can take a look at GraspIt! [http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cmatei/graspit/](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Ecmatei/graspit/) maybe it is helpful for you.

Best Regards
Georg

---

Originally posted by [heppner](https://answers.ros.org/users/20042/heppner/) with karma: 55 on 2015-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0